# Delete non-Excel Files in a folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete non-Excel files in a folder using VBA.

This is code I found from here:[Excel Delete Files](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/437533-excel-delete-files-folder-visual-basic-applications.html).

```
Dim fName As String
fName = Dir("C:\test\*.*")
Do While fName <> ""
    If fName <> "fileA.xls" Then'or .txt or .csv or whatever
       Kill "C:\test\" & fName
    End If
    fName = Dir
Loop
```

I changed the code this way:

```
folderPath = Dir("C:\test\")
Do While folderPath <> ""
  If folderPath <> "*.xls" Then'or .txt or .csv or whatever
     Kill "C:\test\" & folderPath 
  End If
  folderPath = Dir
Loop
```

It is giving me an error saying the file not found. But I have a file in the folder that needs to be deleted.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: CHeck whether file exists at the given location.

Comment: It is there. I ensured that.

Comment: I realize this is a bit editorial, but I would advise against using variable names that don't accurately represent the data being stored therein: specificially, a variable called `folderPath` should probably not be used to store the *file name*.

Comment: Use FSO object instead to identify and exclude files from delete operation.

Comment: @PareshJ can show me an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the below should do as required. Note it is better to use the `Like` operator to compare partial strings, in this case the `Not` operator seeks only those which do not match.

```
strFileName = Dir("C:\test\*")
Do While strFileName <> ""
  If Not lcase$(strFileName) Like "*.xls" Then 'or .txt or .csv or whatever
     Kill "C:\test\" & strFileName
  End If
  strFileName = Dir
Loop
```

Note, if you want it to ignore all Excel files then consider the alternate extensions and explicitly account for them with `And` as follows:

`If Not lcase$(strFileName) Like "*.xls" And Not lcase$(strFileName) Like "*.xlsx" Then`

Remembering .txt, .csv, .xlsm etc.

Comment: Should also probably `lcase$(strFileName) like ...`